# Why GLX or EGL is not enabled when running QT program?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, qt, raspbian-buster

To start with I have to say I was trying to make cross-compilation work for Ubuntu with Raspberry Pi 3+ B. I used this tutorial https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS and QT in version 5.12.4. Tried it on Raspbian Strech and Buster.
My problem is that I can create and deploy programs to Raspberry PI but when they contain OpenGL then I get the error:

> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/accessible" ...
>   QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/accessible" ...
>   QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/xcbglintegrations" ...
>   QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/xcbglintegrations" ...
>   QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
>   QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
>   QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context
>   QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
>   QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context
>   QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
>   QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context
>   QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
>   qt.qpa.backingstore: composeAndFlush: QOpenGLContext creation failed
>   qt.qpa.backingstore: composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
>   qt.qpa.backingstore: composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed

Here is my configuration for build:
https://pastebin.com/MZmRubYd

I have installed every lib required and even additional ones listed here:
https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt5_on_a_Raspberry_Pi

Can somebody help me to find where this error is coming from?